# ReactJS realtime search filter of array of arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, filter

I'm trying to create a realtime filtering search for a long list of items, items are in the form of an array containing arrays with a string and a object, as:

```
const items = [
      ["cats", [
        {name: "name", img: "img/img.jpg"},
        {name: "name2", img: "img2/img.jpg"},
        ...
      ]],
      ["dogs", [
        {name: "name", img: "img/img.jpg"},
        {name: "name2", img: "img2/img.jpg"},
        ...
      ]],
      ...
]
```

and I'm trying to filter it by name values.

What I tried is:

```
export default function Page({ items }) {
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState("");
const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = React.useState(items);
const handleChange = event => {
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
}

useEffect(() => {
    var f=0, results = []
    while (f < items.length){
        if(items[f][1].includes(searchTerm)){
            results.push(result)
        }
        f++
    }
    
    setSearchResults(results);
}, [searchTerm]);

return (
        <div>
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Search"
                value={searchTerm}
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
            {searchResults.map((cl, index) => (
                <div key={index}>
                  <h2>{cl[0]}</h2>
                  <ScrollContainer> 
                    {cl[1].map((item, i) => (
                      <h3>{item.name}</h1>
                    ))}
                  </ScrollContainer>
                </div>
             ))}
```

but it throws error:

> ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 0 failed.

Comment: Do not use `index` as key for iterating `map` function. it reduces your app speed also it is root of weird bugs. reactjs will use it to compare, add a unique string name to it from your Array Items.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please fix your data model. when it is numerable so why you used Array of Array, turn it like this:

```js
const items = [
  { name: "name", img: "img/img.jpg", type: "cat" },
  { name: "name2", img: "img2/img.jpg", type: "cat" },
  ...
  { name: "name", img: "img/img.jpg", type: "dog" },
  { name: "name2", img: "img2/img.jpg", type: "dog" },
  ...
]
```

And about your real-time search, use [`fuse.js`](https://fusejs.io/), you can add it in your project and with simple config it filtered for your, specially `fuse.js` is very comfortable with the above data model. just try it. you will be happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to fix your data like what AmerllicA said but if you have a current data format like that you can convert it like this.

```
const items = [
      ["cats", [
        {name: "name", img: "img/img.jpg"},
        {name: "name2", img: "img2/img.jpg"},
      ]],
 ]

const object = Object.fromEntries(items);
```

this will convert your data into like this:

```
{
  "cats":[{"name":"name","img":"img/img.jpg"},{"name":"name2","img":"img2/img.jpg"}]
}
```

so if you would like to find the cats or dogs

you can do is:

```
const searchTerm = 'cats'
const foundKey = Object.keys(object).find(key => key === searchTerm)
const foundObject = object[foundKey];
```

The output of foundObject would be:

```
"[{"name":"name","img":"img/img.jpg"},{"name":"name2","img":"img2/img.jpg"}]"
```

and if you want to find the specific name for the cat would be like this

```
const searchNameOfFoundObject = 'name';
const findNameOfFoundObject = foundObject.find(value => value.name === searchNameOfFoundObject)
```

then the output of the **findNameOfFoundObject** would be:

```
{"name":"name","img":"img/img.jpg"}
```

But I suggest that you do the searching on the backend if this is a large data this is going to be a burden on your frontend this will make your application slow. You should just send the searchTerm on an api and the data that you will need base on the searchTerm will be the api response this will be handled much more faster on the backend and your frontend react application will be more optimize and user friendly.